# Trouble writing metadata to file

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to keep track of the number of times a certain operation is done on a file by encoding metadata to an alternate data stream. So far I have overridden OnSaveDocument to
write this value to the file on saving:

```
BOOL CEmergenceDoc::OnSaveDocument(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{

CRichEditDoc::OnSaveDocument(lpszPathName); 

CString stream = lpszPathName;
stream += ":iterations";
LPCTSTR newPath = stream;
HANDLE hStream;
DWORD dwRet;

hStream = CreateFile(newPath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0,   

 NULL);
 if(hStream == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
     printf( "Cannot open testfile:stream\n" );
 else {
     CString str;
     CEmergenceView * current = CEmergenceView::GetView();
     str.Format(_T("%d"), current->iterations);
     WriteFile(hStream, str, str.GetLength(), &dwRet, NULL);
}

return TRUE;
}
```

I have also overridden OnFileOpen to read the alternate data stream of the saved file.

```
void CEmergenceApp::OnFileOpen()
{
HANDLE hStream; 
DWORD  dwRet;
char ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};

CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen();
OutputDebugString((CString)"here");
CEmergenceDoc * currentDoc = CEmergenceDoc::GetDoc();
CString currentPath = currentDoc->GetPathName();
currentPath += ":iterations";
OutputDebugString(currentPath);
hStream = CreateFile( currentPath,
                            GENERIC_WRITE,
                         FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                     NULL,
                              OPEN_ALWAYS,
                                        OPEN_EXISTING,
                                     NULL );
  if( hStream == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
     printf( "Cannot open testfile:stream\n" );
  else {
     ReadFile(hStream, ReadBuffer, BUFFERSIZE-1, &dwRet, NULL);
     OutputDebugString((CString)"here");
  }

  CString test;
  test = "";
  test += ReadBuffer;
  OutputDebugString(test);


}
```

As you can see from my code, I'm trying to test whether this is working by printing out
whatever is in ReadBuffer, but this is not printing out anything even though it does get to ReadFile when I open a file. Can someone please have a look at this and tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

EDIT:

I did the following command in cmd:

more < testfile:stream

and it appears it IS writing data to the alternate data stream....so the problem must lie in reading it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments:

a) you don't seem to be closing the stream handle `hStream` in either of the functions

b) check the return values in the `WriteFile()` and `ReadFile()` calls

c) in `CEmergenceApp::OnFileOpen()`, open the file using `GENERIC_READ` or `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`